# Problema com iteração em lista usando a função any()

Tags: python

Criei um script para apagar arquivos de uma pasta e suas respectivas subpastas. Essas subpastas estão nomeadas da seguinte forma:
1.GERAL_%i com i variando de 1 a 137. 
Entretanto, só quero apagar os arquivos da pasta 89 em diante, não quero apagar as pastas 1 a 88. Fiz o script abaixo:

```py
import os

my_path = os.getcwd()
foldersToSkip = list(f'1.GERAL_{i}' for i in range (1,89))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
    if not any(x in root for x in foldersToSkip):
        for file in files:
            if any(y in file for y in filesToDel):
                fileToDel = os.path.join(root,file)
                os.remove(fileToDel)
```

Aparentemente era pra funcionar, mas o código não apagou arquivo nenhum. Quando debuguei, percebi o erro. Notei que o comando *x in root for x in foldersToSkip* não faz uma comparação exata entre a string *x* e a string da lista *foldersToSkip*, mas bastava a string da lista estar contida na string *x*. 
Por exemplo: o script não apaga arquivos da subpasta **1_GERAL_90** por que existe a string **1_GERAL_9** na lista *foldersToSkip*, e quando ele faz a comparação a saída acaba sendo true.

A minha dúvida então é, como eu mudo meu código pra fazer com que essa comparação seja exata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente a função [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) retorna uma tupla com três valores:

1. `dirpath`, uma *string*
2. `dirnames`, uma lista
3. `filenames`, uma lista

Quando você faz `x in root`, seu `root` será uma *string* e, portanto, estará verificando se a *string* possui como *substring* o valor desejado. Por isso que aconteceu o comportamento que você verificou, de pular o diretório `1_GERAL_90`, pois a verificação que você executou foi `'1_GERAL_9' in '1_GERAL_90'`.

Para fazer o que você precisa, você pode simplificar utilizando o módulo `pathlib` junto com o `shutil`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import re

def must_be_deleted(name):
    groups = re.match(r'1\.GERAL_(\d+)', name)
    if groups and int(groups[1]) >= 89:
        return True
    return False


path = Path.cwd()

for item in path:
    if item.is_dir() and must_be_deleted(item.name):
        shutil.rmtree(item)
```

Basicamente é percorrido todos os itens dentro de `path`, se for um diretório e o número do final do nome é maior ou igual a 89, o diretório é excluído.

---

Como já é definido que você precisa excluir os diretórios com o número entre 89 e 137, não precisa utilizar a expressão regular, basta percorrer um valor neste intervalo e excluir o diretório que existir. Esse detalhe acabou passando despercebido inicialmente, por isso sugeri a expressão regular.

Assim, poderia ficar como:

```py
import pathlib
import shutil

cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()

for i in range(89, 138):
    item = cwd / f'1.GERAL_{i}'
    if item.is_dir():
        shutil.rmtree(item)
```

Comment: Então, eu não quero apagar as pastas, mas apenas os arquivos dentro das pastas. Mas isso só vai mudar o a parte final do código. A solução que eu procurava é a função `must_be_deleted` que você apresentou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Me conte mais sobre como você quer que funcione essa comparação de string com inteiro aqui: ` if groups and int(groups[1]) >= 89:`

Comment: @jsbueno Qual comparação de string com inteiro?

Comment: O `shutil` foi utilizado para remover diretórios não vazios, pois havia entendido que eram estes que deveriam ser excluídos, não apenas os arquivos neles.

Comment: ah - nossa - tem  conversão ali - eu que já vi regexps pra lidar com números em sequência e já enchi minha cabeça de "não funciona" antes de ler tudo.  Mas vendo com calma, está legal sim.

Comment: é - eu estava pensando aqui - o pathlib não tem equivalentes a tudo no shutil, e nem um equivalente ao "os.walk" - é uma pena. Tem o "Path.iterdir" para uma busca não recursiva, e o  "Path.glob" para uma busca recursiva - mas ela é "eager", e não lazy como o os.walk

Comment: Até pensei em não usar a regex - a primeira versão do código até era `name[name.rfind('_')+1:]`, mas como isso abriria espaço para outros formatos de nomes terminados com este sufixo, acabei colocando a regex para simplificar

Comment: @jsbueno só agora vi que na pergunta ele limita até 137 o nome da pasta e entendi o que você quis dizer. Eu não tinha visto essa limitação de início, assim dá para fazer sem a regex bem tranquilamente mesmo... Editarei